# How to calclulate multiplicative inverse of e mod $\phi(n)$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

In this [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#A_working_example) article about RSA, At step 5, How are they calclulating value of $d$? Can anybody give me a step-by-step explanation?

> Compute $d$, the modular multiplicative inverse of $e \pmod{\phi(n)}$ yielding $d=2753$.

Comment: Why are you linking to an old version of the page?

Comment: Copy paste issue :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most efficient way would be the Euclidean algorithm.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

You use the Euclidean algorithm to find $d, a$ such that $d \cdot e + a \cdot \phi(n) = 1$.  Taking this mod $\phi(n)$ gives $d \cdot e \equiv 1$.

For your specific case where $\phi(n) = 3120$ and $e = 17$, you start with
$3120 / 17$, which is 183 with a remainder of 9.  Write this as:

$$3120 = 17 \cdot 183 + 9$$
Now, repeat this process with 17 and 9.
$$17 = 9 \cdot 1 + 8$$
Now, repeat this process with 9 and 8.
$$9 = 8 \cdot 1 + 1$$
Now that you have obtained 1, "solve" for 1 using back substitution, with an end goal of getting 1 as a linear combination of 3120 and 17.  First, the three above equations become

$$\begin{align*}
  1 &= 9 - 8 \\
  8 &= 17 - 9 \\
  9 &= 3120 - 17 \cdot 183
\end{align*}$$

So, doing back substitution gives

$$1 = 9 - 8 = 9 - (17 - 9) = 9 \cdot 2 - 17 = [3120 - 17 \cdot 183] \cdot 2 - 17 = 3120 \cdot 2 - 17 \cdot 367$$

As I said above, taking everything mod 3120 gives
$$17 \cdot -367 \equiv 1$$
and since $-367 + 3120 = 2753$, we see that $-367 \equiv 2753$ mod 3120.  Thus, $-367$, or $2753$ is the multiplicative inverse of 17 mod 3120.

Comment: Can you use this in a example?

Comment: @iraSenthil I read your question more carefully and understood you wanted to see the detail, so I added it.

Comment: How did you know it's the fastest? Can we get more fast? Stop me from finding possibly faster way. Please.

Answer (score 3):

You use the [Extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

You know $\phi(n)$ (because you know $n=pq$ with $p$ and $q$ primes, so that $\phi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)$). So it is an easy matter to apply the Extended Euclidean Algorithm to $e$ and to $(p-1)(q-1)$ to obtain integers $x$ and $y$ such that
$$1 = xe + y\phi(n).$$
(If $\gcd(e,\phi(n))\gt 1$, you are supposed to pick a different $e$).

The number $d$ you are looking for is the coefficient $x$ in this expression.

In the specific example given: $p=61$, $q=53$, $n=61\times 53=3233$, $\phi(n) = 60\times 52 = 3120$, and $e=17$.

Divide $\phi(n)$ by $e$ with remainder:
$$3120 = 183\times {\color{magenta}{17}} + {\color{blue}9}. \tag{1}$$
Now divide ${\color{magenta}{17}}$ by the remainder ${\color{blue}9}$:
$${\color{magenta}{17}} = 1\times {\color{blue}9} + {\color{red}8}.\tag{2}$$
Now divide ${\color{blue}9}$ by the remainder ${\color{red}8}$:
$${\color{blue}9} = 1\times{\color{red}8} + {\color{green}1}.\tag{3}$$
This will be the last step in the Euclidean algorithm, since when you divide ${\color{red}8}$ by $\color{green}1$, you will obtain a remainder of $0$; the gcd is the last nonzero remainder.

Now backtrack to write ${\color{green}1}$ as a linear combination of $3120$ and $17$:
$$\begin{align*}
{\color{green}1} &= {\color{blue}9} - 1\times{\color{red}8} &\text{(by (3))}\\
&= {\color{blue}9} - 1\times({\color{magenta}{17}} - 1\times{\color{blue}9}) &\text{(by (2))}\\
&= {\color{blue}9} - {\color{magenta}{17}} + {\color{blue}9}\\
&= 2\times{\color{blue}9} - 1\times{\color{magenta}{17}}\\
&= 2\times(3120 - 183\times{\color{magenta}{17}}) - 1\times{\color{magenta}{17}}&\text{(by (1))}\\
&= 2\times 3120 - 366\times{\color{magenta}{17}} - {\color{magenta}{17}}\\
&= 2\times 3120 - 367\times{\color{magenta}{17}}.
\end{align*}$$
So $d\equiv -367 \equiv 3120-367 \equiv 2753\pmod{3120}$.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: @iraSenthil [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242) is a description of one simple way to manually execute the extended Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time trying to figure out the algebra from the above answer. I personally like parenthesis. They tend to make math more clear not less clear so i am rewriting the above answer for people that have the same preference. I hope this helps some people, and great job to the person above me. It helped a lot.

Now backtrack to write 1 as a linear combination of 3120 and 17:

```
 1=9−1×8,
 1=9−1×(17−1×9),
 1=9+(-1)(17-9),
 1=9−17+9,
 1=2×9−17,
 1=(2x9)-(1x17),
 1=2×[3120−(183×17)]−1×17,
 1=(2)(3120)-(2)(183x17)-1x17,
 1=(2x3120)+(-2)(183x17)-1x17,
 1=(2x3120)+(-366x17)-(1x17),
 1=(2x3120)+[17(-366-1)],
 1=(2x3120)+[17x-367],
 1=(2x3120)+[-367x17],
 1=(2x3120)+(-1x367x17),
 1=(2x3120)-(1x367x17),
 1=(2x3120)-(367x17),
```

I know many of these parenthesis are not necessary, but I believe they make the math easier to follow. It is just my preference, and I typed this up to help the next person who has the same preference. Anyway, thanks for the above answers. They helped me a great deal.